# How can I draw this eigen value problem related figure in latex?

Tags: floats, diagrams

How can I draw this eigenvalue problem related figure in latex?

[image: how to draw this in latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What package do you use to draw figure in latex? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  (171,263.77) -- (486,263.77)(334.8,95) -- (334.8,364.6) (479,258.77) -- (486,263.77) -- (479,268.77) (329.8,102) -- (334.8,95) -- (339.8,102) (354.8,258.77) -- (354.8,268.77)(374.8,258.77) -- (374.8,268.77)(394.8,258.77) -- (394.8,268.77)(414.8,258.77) -- (414.8,268.77)(434.8,258.77) -- (434.8,268.77)(454.8,258.77) -- (454.8,268.77)(314.8,258.77) -- (314.8,268.77)(294.8,258.77) -- (294.8,268.77)(274.8,258.77) -- (274.8,268.77)(254.8,258.77) -- (254.8,268.77)(234.8,258.77) -- (234.8,268.77)(214.8,258.77) -- (214.8,268.77)(194.8,258.77) -- (194.8,268.77)(329.8,243.77) -- (339.8,243.77)(329.8,223.77) -- (339.8,223.77)(329.8,203.77) -- (339.8,203.77)(329.8,183.77) -- (339.8,183.77)(329.8,163.77) -- (339.8,163.77)(329.8,143.77) -- (339.8,143.77)(329.8,123.77) -- (339.8,123.77)(329.8,283.77) -- (339.8,283.77)(329.8,303.77) -- (339.8,303.77)(329.8,323.77) -- (339.8,323.77)(329.8,343.77) -- (339.8,343.77) ;
\draw   ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9358231190029724] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (295.8,263.77) .. controls (295.8,231.18) and (322.22,204.77) .. (354.8,204.77) .. controls (387.38,204.77) and (413.8,231.18) .. (413.8,263.77) .. controls (413.8,296.35) and (387.38,322.77) .. (354.8,322.77) .. controls (322.22,322.77) and (295.8,296.35) .. (295.8,263.77) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp43361731818661586] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (253.61,263.77) .. controls (253.61,207.89) and (298.92,162.58) .. (354.8,162.58) .. controls (410.68,162.58) and (455.99,207.89) .. (455.99,263.77) .. controls (455.99,319.65) and (410.68,364.96) .. (354.8,364.96) .. controls (298.92,364.96) and (253.61,319.65) .. (253.61,263.77) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp14620383009775817] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 80; green, 227; blue, 194 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (234,267.47) .. controls (234,223.01) and (270.04,186.97) .. (314.5,186.97) .. controls (358.96,186.97) and (395,223.01) .. (395,267.47) .. controls (395,311.93) and (358.96,347.97) .. (314.5,347.97) .. controls (270.04,347.97) and (234,311.93) .. (234,267.47) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (491,256.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\mathrm{Re}( \lambda )$};
% Text Node
\draw (314,74.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\mathrm{Im}( \lambda )$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code (you can delete elements you don't like):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
        % grid and axis
        \draw[gray!15] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (-6,0)--(6.5,0) node[right] () {\small Re$(\lambda)$};
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (0,-6)--(0,6) node[above] () {\small Im$(\lambda)$};
        \foreach \i in {-6,-5,...,-1,1,2,...,5}{
            \draw[thick] (\i,0)--(\i,-.05) node[below] () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \draw[thick] (0,\i)--(-.05,\i) node[left]  () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \node[below left] at (0,0) {\footnotesize \bfseries 0};
        }
        %circles
        \draw[cyan] (1,0) circle(3) ;
        \draw[red] (-1,0) circle(4) ;
        \draw[blue] (1,0) circle(5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```